# Codefirst Migrations not working with EntityFramework, MVC5, ComplexType and fluent

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, fluent, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I like to use composition to group up like properties in a class so that they are easier to use when the number of fields increase. My question is, can entity framework handle modeling when we use composition and ComplexTypes in a class? When I use the two together, I get the following error during `migrations`:

> The expression 'x => x.AllQuantities.OnHandUom' is not a valid
>   property expression. The expression should represent a property: C#:
>   't => t.MyProperty'  VB.Net: 'Function(t) t.MyProperty'.

Here is the code. This is a simple model.

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public AllQuantities AllQuantities { get; set; }
}
```

Note, `AllQuantities` is a Complex Type added through composition (I want the fields to appear in the same table as the products, but I want to group them under AllQuanties (Actually I have many more fields, but I have simplified the problem for here.))

```
[ComplexType]
public class AllQuantities
{
    public double OnHand { get; set; }
    public Uom OnHandUom { get; set; }
    public int OnHandUomID { get; set; }
}
```

Please note in my Uom class, I am trying to set up a navigation property back to products through the complex type.

```
public class Uom
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double QtyInUom { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Product> OnHandUoms { get; set; }
}
```

Then, I have used the following fluent code to set up the model in my context file so that the navigation property works.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
        .HasRequired(x => x.AllQuantities.OnHandUom)
        .WithMany(y => y.OnHandUoms)
        .HasForeignKey(z => z.AllQuantities.OnHandUomID)
        .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Note the

> "HasRequired(x => `x.AllQuantities.OnHandUom`)."

I believe the dot notation is causing some kind of a problem. To my mind, it shouldn't.

I have tried the model creation by adding all the fields from my ComplexType AllQuantities to the product directly, as per normal, then everything works, however, when I separate the two as listed above, I get the error mentioned earlier. I would like to use the ComplexType so that I can group like fields.

My question is, is there any way to make the above work with a ComplexType and compostion?